# CodeDeploy prevents me from deleting instances in EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to set up a project and my BeforeInstall scripts are failing. I am working on this problem, but it creates a side effect that every time I attempt to deploy I get new instances. I'm up to 22. When I try to delete instances they reappear later. Something is forcing them to stay alive.

I'm not fully familiar with what is going on here, but my theory is that CodeDeploy creates a new AutoScaling group for each deploy, and those are configured to have 3 instances.

So my question is:

1. Is the above what is going on?
2. Why does CodeDeploy create a new autoscaling group each time?
3. If (2) is the correct behavior, why doesn't it delete the old group OR why doesn't it delete the new group when the deploy fails.
4. Related to (3) do I have something configured in correctly?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If your instances are part of an AutoScaling group, terminating instances doesn't help as ASG will re launch new instances to match set capacity. You need to set AutScalingGroup properties (Desired=0) to terminate instances without lauching them again. Also what kind of deployment, is it in-place or blue/green deployment ? As you were saying codedeploy launches a new ASG, I think It's blue/green deployment ? Can you verify this from codedeploy console ?

Answer (score 1):

"Why does CodeDeploy create a new autoscaling group?" - CodeDeploy does not create a new autoscaling group unless you are creating a blue green deployment with Automatically copy Auto Scaling group option selected. The behavior you are getting into is because if you use CodeDeploy once to deploy to your instances in an Autoscaling group, there is a hook that gets established between CodeDeploy and Auto Scaling group and whenever your deployment to any of the instances fail Austoscaling marks that instance as a bad instance and spins up a new instance and notifies CodeDeploy to deploy the last successful revision to that instance. For more details refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/integrations-aws-auto-scaling.html.

To resolve this issue, you can either set the autoscaling group desired value to 0 to terminate all instances or suspend the scaling policy.